# Kohn anomaly and avoided crossing (or anticrossing/level repulsion)

Tags: density-functional-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-mechanics, phonons, solid-state-physics

**Kohn Anomaly** and **Avoided Crossing (Anticrossing/Level Repulsion)** are terms that are found to be used when discussing phonon dispersion. The former ([see](http://www.condmat.physics.manchester.ac.uk/pdf/mesoscopic/publications/graphene/Naturemat_2007Raman.pdf) last paragraph, page 198) is related to electron-phonon coupling, while the latter ([refer](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mtphys.2018.02.005) 2nd paragraph, page 55) is related to phonon-phonon coupling. Both phenomena lower the phonon frequency.

**Are these concepts same, related or different?**

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any update, but for the sake of curiosity I would like to recieve the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response AbPhys! If anyone has an answer, they're encouraged to **ping me in a comment** here, or to write a Flag asking for the question to be re-opened!